# freeze Gridview header for latest version of Firefox and IE browsers

Tags: asp.net, firefox, gridview

Is there a solution that could fix the issue on freeze gridview header for the latest version of Firefox and IE browsers?

Seems to be that all available solutions I have encountered are not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i wrote jQuery plug-in can fixed header and freeze column, it can be apply to GridView.
see the image:

[image]

look the website: http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

Maybe you can try my solution.